# User.save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'update_fields' while login

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am developing a blog website and i was working on editing profile information and made some changes in profile template and after making changes to template and suddenly get this error while login it was working before editing templates and now registration is also not working  and i am not able  login using admin panel

**User.save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'update_fields'**
**Models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    profile_image =  models.ImageField(("Profile Image"), 
                        upload_to='ProfileImage', 
                        max_length=None,
                        blank = True,null = True)
    profile = models.TextField(("Profile"),blank = True)

    def save(self):
        super().save()  

        img = Image.open(self.profile_image.path)

        if img.height > 400 or img.width > 400:
            new_img = (400, 400)
            img.thumbnail(new_img)
            img.save(self.profile_image.path)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username'
```

**Views.py**

```
class userLogin(View):
     def get(self,request):
          return render(request,"account/login.html")

     def post(self,request):
          if request.method == "POST":
               username = request.POST['username']
               password = request.POST['password']
               #try:
               user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
               if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {username}")
                    return redirect('/')
               else:
                    messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")


          return render(request,'account/login.html')
```

I dont know what happened suddenly i didnt change anything other than things is teamplate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should accept `*args` and `**kwargs` in the save method: the [**`.save(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) accepts a number of parameters, and you thus should *not* alter the signature. Otherwise certain parts of the Django logic will assume that they can call the `.save(…)` method with these parameters, and thus fail to do so.

You thus can accept an arbitrary number of positional and named parameters, and pass these to the super call:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # …
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        img = Image.open(self.profile_image.path)
        if img.height > 400 or img.width > 400:
            new_img = (400, 400)
            img.thumbnail(new_img)
            img.save(self.profile_image.path)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: whats the point of adding *args and **kwargs i mean it was working fine i was able to upload photo and render that on my template . sorry f but i dont  understand why this is causing this problem

Comment: @Roshan: the `.save()` of an object exports a certain signature, that is used by a signal triggered when you login to set the `last_login` field of the user.

Comment: @Roshan: certain parts of the Django logic thus expect that they can call the `.save(..)` method with the `update_fields`, `using`, etc. parameters. The fact that you defined a save method that does not take any parameters, will result in Django logic that can not work with this. You should therefore always carefully preserve the signature.